# Avoid repeating params in stack navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation

I am building the auth part of the stack navigation for a react navigation app, and ended with something like thiss:

```
 <Stack.Screen
        name="a"
        component={a}
        initialParams={{ url }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="f" component={f} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="b"
        component={b}
        initialParams={{ url }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="c"
        component={c}
        initialParams={{ url }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="d"
        component={d}
        initialParams={{ url }}
      />
```

Is there any way I can avoid adding the url initialParams everywhere and add it maybe to the stack group screen around?

I tried to add it in the screenOptions prop in the stack group around, but didn't work.

Do you guys have any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, it is just an shortUrlId. Basicly {shortUrlId: shortUrlId}

Comment: If you are using redux, then you could probably store it inside the redux store and access it inside the screens needed. That would be cleaner I guess. Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an object and use spread operator on components.

```
 const initialParams = { initialParams: { url } };


 <Stack.Screen
        name="a"
        component={a}
        {...initialParams}
      />
```